# How can I stop my parallax div having a blurred background?

Tags: html, css

I have a div in a page that I am trying to apply a parallax background to using just html and css.

The problem is the image appears zoomed in and blurry

You can see my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/lveale/pen/RwbRGLe)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.column1,
.column2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 1200px;
}

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/mXPXj7Y/gridimage6.jpg');
  width: 425px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="parallax">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I'm having is that even though my background image is the same dimensions as the div it's appearing massively zoomed in.
There seems to be something strange with the size of my div as if I set the background-size to contain it doesn't display right either, like the div is too narrow.

I'm kind of baffled and suspect it's something simple that I am missing...

I expected the image to fit the div since the proportions and sizes are the same, but it is still zooming in on the image as though it thinks the div is different dimensions to what it is set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment), `background-attachment: fixed` fixes the background relative to the viewport rather than the container - the function becomes a little more apparent from the little demo that you can see on the top of the page (see how the background remains fixed regardless of both scrollbar positions).

Depending on your exact use case, you could either pick an image that accounts for this, or use background-size + background-position relative to viewport sizes.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.column1,
.column2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 1200px;
}

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: right center;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/mXPXj7Y/gridimage6.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="parallax">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update: translateZ version

```css
/* important: otherwise you'll have a "border" around the page */
body { margin: 0; }

/* important: must encompass the page; scrolls instead of original body element and applies parallax */
.container {
  width:100%;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scro
  ll;
}

/* not important: columns from the original example */
.column1, .column2 {
  width:50%;
  height:1200px;
  float:left;
}

/* makes sure that you can only see the parallax element through its "window" */
.clipper {
  width: 450px;
  height: 425px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax {
  /* important; figure out a good scale yourself */
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(3);
  /* not important: whatever we were going to show here */
  height: 450px;
  width:425px;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/mXPXj7Y/gridimage6.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    (irrelevant text in left column)
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    (...some text before the parallax element so that you can see the effect better)
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    (...more text and a few linebreaks)
    <div class="clipper">
      <div class="parallax">
      </div>
    </div>
    (some text after)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I hadn't realised that background-attachment:fixed; worked off of viewport size.

You said that:
"Depending on your exact use case, you could either pick an image that accounts for this, or use background-size + background-position relative to viewport sizes."

How might that look? Or how else could I do this without background-attachment:fixed? (I've read that it's possible using css transforms?)
Thanks

Comment: If your image is big enough to comfortably cover the entire port (despite the half of it being covered by the non-parallax half of the page), it will function correctly; if your parallax div has a fixed pixel size, you'd use that for background-size; CSS transform approach relies on enabling perspective and setting translateZ+scale, [this](https://codepen.io/karldanninger/full/NwzMzN/) is a good example and "CSS parallax translateZ" is a good search term for those.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've had a go with the translateZ method on my codepen, but can't seem to get a parallax effect with it at all. All the examples I can find are for parallax headers and similar rather than for small nested divs, so maybe that's where I'm going wrong, I'm not sure

Comment: You were missing overflow properties on the `.container` - this is needed for this approach to work. I added a second snippet to the answer.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. A couple of questions: Is it not possible to do this without having to put a overflow-y:scroll on the containing element? I don't really want them to have to scroll within the container to see the effect or to have a scroll bar on the div.

Also the margin-top is pushing the image down the page, is there any way around that?

Comment: Added comments for maximum clarity. You have a single element encompassing the page and scrolling instead of the original body tag [while applying parallax]. Margin was there to make it easier to see whether the parallax works at all. Stripped irrelevant styles from original code and the parallax example.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the background-attachment: fixed in your .parallax. This seemed to fix it for me in the codepen link.

Comment: Hi Kendra, removing background-attachment:fixed does make it fit the div as a background image, but it loses the parallax scrolling effect that I want.